# read data from a java applet (preferably with js)

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, applet

Here's my problem. I have an application that shows some KPIs... the problem is that it displays those KPIs through a Java applet (and I don't have access to it's source). I need only a few data from that applet. Is there a way to parse data from a Java applet? I would like to parse it with Javascript. Would that be possible?

Comment: Key Performance Index

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to call Java applet methods from JavaScript ([read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)), but it would have to be set up like this already.  If you don't have access to the source, perhaps inspect Java console output and/or use 'jar' and 'javap' commands to inspect the classes to see if there is something you can call.